# How many matrices have trace equal to givan trace?

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix

I have given a trace 'n' of matrix.And I want to find out that how many matrices(of order 2*2 only) are there whose trace is equals to 'n' and all the matrices must be ***positive*** invertible , i.e their determinant must be greator than `'0'`.

```
For ex:
trace=3
No.of matrices=2

trace=4
No.of matrices=11

trace=5
No.of matrices=30
```

I have written a code for this,but it is not efficient because my code giving output successfully for `n=1500`,after that I'm getting time limit exceeded.
Can anyone help me?

My code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int t,n,nsot,i,j,l;
    int arr[2000],k;
    unsigned long long  sum1=0,sum2=0,sum=0;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        sum1=0;
        sum2=0;
        //sum=0;
        scanf("%d",&n);
        nsot=n/2;
        for(i=1;i<=nsot;i++)
        {
            arr[i]=i*(n-i);
            //printf("%d ",arr[i]);
            sum1=0;
                for(k=1;k<arr[i];k++)
                {
                    //printf("%f\n",ceil(arr[i]/k));
                    sum1=sum1+((arr[i] - 1) / k);

                }
                if(i==(n-i))
            sum=sum1;
            else
            sum=0;

            //printf("%d\n",sum);
            //printf("%llu",sum2);
            sum2=sum1+sum2;
        }
        printf("%llu\n",(2*sum2)-sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: the number of 2x2 invertible matrices with trace = 3 is certainly greater than 2

Comment: How are you getting `11` for `n = 4` if the elements must all be positive? `trace = sum of elements on the main diagonal`, so you can only have `1 3`, `2 2`, `3 1`? Or do you mean that not all elements must be positive, only the determinant?

Comment: all the elements must be greator than 0.

Comment: [1, 2;2, 2], [2, 5; 0, 1], [2,0;0 1] ... do you mean diagonal matrices?

Comment: the number of 2x2 invertible matrices with trace = 3 is certainly equals to  2 @MHH

Comment: Then what are, say, four `2x2` invertible matrices with strictly positive elements and trace = `4`?

Comment: Invertible means determinant != 0. Must they be invertible, or must the determinant be strictly positive?

Comment: for trace=3  [1,1;1,2] and [2,1;1,1] @MHH

Comment: Do you have to use `long long`? It might run faster with just `long`.

Comment: For square matrix 'A' condition of invertibility is |A|!=0 and for positive invertibilty |A|>0.

Comment: There is no problem with datatypes!!

Comment: Your innermost loop can be replaced with a simple calculation.

Comment: @madhurgarg That wasn't my question. Stop being rude to people and start answering their questions properly.

Comment: @ooga can you explain me how to that??

Comment: Figure it out yourself. You seem to think you know everything.

Comment: Sorry!! but I think if I use just 'long',then wouldn't get correct answer for larger inputs such as 2500.

Comment: Actually I have used 'long' as well but still getting time limit exceeded

Comment: Can anyone please explain me??

Comment: @madhurgarg I can see from the code and reading the conversation that you're working in $M_2(\mathbb{N})$ but off the bat you should probably specify that the entries have to be in $\mathbb{N}$...

Comment: @DanZimm what are you talking about,i don't understand $M_2(\mathbb{N})$....what is this?

Comment: @madhurgarg sorry, I guess I use latex too much ;P, the natural numbers. You're only interested in positive integers. At first I thought you were using general Reals, then I thought non-negative integers, but you should specify that it's positive integers.

Answer (score 1):

So I'm guessing you want positive matrix elements and determinant > 0.

The possible values for the trace are `[1, n - 1]; [2, n - 2] ...`, so `n -1` values.

We will check, for each of these (`O(n) checks`), in how many ways we can fill in the remaining elements of the matrix such that the determinant stays positive.

Let the matrix be:

```
a1 a3
a4 a2
```

The determinant is then `a1*a2 - a3*a4`. For a fixed `a1` and `a2`, iterate `a3` from `1` to `n - 1`. You'll then have to solve:

```
a1*a2 - x*a4 > 0
a1*a2 > x*a4
x < a1*a2 / a4
```

So you can find `x` in `O(1)` => total complexity `O(n^2)`, which should be very fast.

This seems to be what you're doing, except your innermost loop makes it `O(n^3)` (you also iterate `x`):

```
l=1;
while(k*l<arr[i])
{
    sum1++; 
    l++;
}
```

Say `k` = 10 and `arr[i] = 103`. What will `l` be at the end? Can you find a relation between `10`, `103` and the final value of `l`? That will be your formula.

Comment: you say that: x<a1*a2/4.So we have to iterate x also, till x<a1*a2/4 ?

Comment: @madhurgarg - no, you don't. Read the rest of my answer.

Comment: I've rewritten my code.It is somewhat faster than previous but still time limit exceeding as checked by 'ideone'.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a specialization of the well known problem of integer partitioning. p(n) is the number of ways of writing n as a sum of positive integers (the order does not matter), and p(n,k) is the number of ways to write n as a sum of k integers. Your problem starts from p(n,2), and adds some extra conditions. There is a wealth of literature on integer partitioning algorithms, you should start from one of them.
However, mind that integer partitioning is NP-complete, so it's natural that it will diverge quickly as n grows.

Comment: While strictly speaking you're correct, this hardly helps, since `p(n,2)` is trivial to find and the problem focuses on something completely different.